# Remove shadow from document opencv Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am brighten the doc using following code to remove shadow from it.

```
Mat brighten = mat.clone();
brighten.convertTo(brighten, -1, 1, 50);
Core.addWeighted(brighten, 0.8, mat, 0.2, 0, mat);
```

It takes min 2 sec to brighten the doc and also this brighten the whole doc. So this is not good idea

sample image. 
[image]
Is there any better solution to remove the shadow from doc.

Comment: `Core.addWeighted` is a fairly simple operation, and it is highly unlikely that it may take 2 seconds to perform this operation. Can you attach the image dimensions as well ? Downscaling the image may help if dimensions are very large.

Comment: It's not easy to remove the shadow, my result is also bad. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Y3G.jpg

Comment: @Silencer, May I know how you tried, Can you share code?

Comment: Sorry,  for NDA. @Gunaseelan

Comment: @Silencer Your result is better than my result. Thats why I am asking. If you don't mind just share a snippet.